# How to get values from soapobject which is coming from server

Tags: android, soap

I am getting a response from the server while doing soap parsing using Ksoap parser. I want to get specific values from object attributes. I am using a magento method catalogCategoryInfo and now want to get the children property separately.

Here I am getting catalogCategoryInfo:

```
request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "catalogCategoryInfo");

            request.addProperty("sessionId",sessionId );
            request.addProperty("categoryId","2" );

            env.setOutputSoapObject(request);


            androidHttpTransport.call("", env);

            result =  (JSONObject)env.getResponse();                    

            System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"+result);
```

and output is:

```
catalogCategoryInfo{category_id=2; is_active=1; position=1; level=1; parent_id=1; all_children=2,400,407,408,410,402,411,420,421,422,424,425,426,428,430,431,432,433,474,475,526,404,429,444,445,446,447,448,449,450,451,453,454,455,456,457,458,459,460,461,405,465,466,467,468,406,476,478,479,480,481,512,513,514,516,517,518,519,520,521,522,523,524,525,527,528,533,535,537,539,540,544; children=400,402,404,405,406,512,527; created_at=2016-02-04 05:39:36; updated_at=2016-02-06 07:28:28; name=Default Category; url_key=default-category; path=1/2; url_path=/default-category; children_count=71; display_mode=PRODUCTS; is_anchor=0; available_sort_by=ArrayOfString{}; default_sort_by=position; }
```

Now I want to get only the `children=400,402,404,405,406,512,527;` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get Values from JSON object using key values
1. First get parent object
JSONObject resObj=result.getJSONObject("catalogCategoryInfo");
2. get values from object, its look not formatted json

```
children=400,402,404,405,406,512,527
```

children is key, if you want one by one value ask Backend return as JSON Array.

```
if children is String 
string value=resOnj.getString("children");
else children is int
int value=resOnj.getInt("children");
```

Comment: I am asking  the  code to get parent object in JSONObject, so can you please send me the code..

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.
we can achieve it by using following code:
//fetch category information
                request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "catalogCategoryInfo");

```
            request.addProperty("sessionId  ",sessionId );
            request.addProperty("categoryId","2");                
            env.setOutputSoapObject(request);                               
            androidHttpTransport.call("urn:Magento/catalogCategoryInfo",env);       
            SoapObject response =   (SoapObject) env.getResponse();  

            Object children = (Object)response.getProperty(6);
```

Comment: here 6 is the index  of "children" proerty